# Integrate ext js 6 with Django backend

Tags: django, extjs6

I am developing my UI in sencha ext js 6. My Backend code is written in Django.
Currently Im making cross domain requests to fetch and load data to my UI from django. However, I am planning to have both the ext js and django to reside in the same domain. How can I achieve this?

I have tried various approaches to integrate these two pieces like putting the ext js inside of static folder in django app. But none of my approaches worked. There seems to be no examples/ documentation on this topic.

Any suggestions on how to do this in ext js 6. What should be the structure of the extjs6 inside the django app.

Comment: In your Django app, do you use Django REST framework?

Maybe this will help: http://mydeveloperlogbook.blogspot.com.br/2016/05/python-django-18-restful-api-extjs-6.html